# laravel 5.8 and Vue "TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.8

In my laravel project I'm using a package called LaraToaster
[LaraToaster](https://github.com/theorythree/LaraToaster)

i do what the package required

**LaraToaster.vue**

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['message','type'],
    mounted() {
      this.$toast.open({
        message: this.message,
        type: this.type,
        duration: 2000,
        queue: true,
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import Vue from 'vue'
import Buefy from 'buefy'

Vue.use(Buefy)

Vue.component('laratoaster', require('./components/LaraToaster.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

**ContactController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Toaster;
use App\Mail\ContactMail;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
  public function create()
  {
    return view('contact.create');
  }

  public function store()
  {
      $data = request()->validate([
        'name'    => 'required',
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required|min:3',
      ]);
      Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new ContactMail($data));
      Toaster::success("Your Message has been sent.");
      return redirect('contact');
  }
}
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="overflow-auto" lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    // head content
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <main class="py-4">
            <div class="container">
                @yield('content')

            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

@section('head', 'Contact Us')
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column is-three-fifths is-offset-one-fifth">
         {!! Toaster::toast() !!}
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

The component is registered but it gives me error

> [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'open' of undefined"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources/js/components/LaraToaster.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buefy recently changed its API to put everything in the `$buefy` namespace. See:

https://github.com/buefy/buefy/commit/5ba5094ed846608ae32bbadba5e79c01c4650f70

From 0.8.0 you need to use:

```js
this.$buefy.toast.open
```

I haven't used LaraToaster but from a quick skim of the code it looks like this should be enough to fix it. If you still have compatibility issues you may want to use the previous version of Buefy until LaraToaster is updated.